# How to tell when to fetch new image?

Tags: php, image, cron, mirror

I have a copy of 350+ images on my sever, when a person tries to view one, if it is more than 5 minutes old, I want my sever to check with another website that I am mirroring data from(they insist on me mirroring instead of hotlinking) and get the newest copy. Any thoughts on how to do this?

I can do a cron script and get all of the images, but there are problems doing that.(My host limits me to once every 15 minutes, I would have to get a lot of images that my users may or may not actually view.)

I am thinking there should be a way to do this in PHP, but I have no idea where I would start.

Comment: make one of the column a date field and compare it with now() whenever a person wants to view one.

Comment: I can check the image stats and see when it was last updated/created compared to now. I have no idea how to call the script that would make the check as the images are loaded dynamically by the user so the hosting php page does not know which if any are loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could serve the images via a php script that allows you to do the necessary checks before displaying the image.

```
<img src="/index.php/image-name.jpg">
```

Below is one option for the checks

```
// get the image name from the uri
$image = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[2];
// check if the image exists
if (is_file($image)) {
    // get the file age
    $age = filemtime($image);
    if ($age < time() - (60*5)) { // 5 mins old
        // file too old so check for new one
            // do your check and serve the appropriate image
    }
    else
    {
        // get the image and serve it to the user
        $fp = fopen($image, 'rb');
        // send the right headers
        header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($image));
        // dump the picture and stop the script
        fpassthru($fp);
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: `$image = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[2];` Took me a while to debug that line. the [2] was causing the problem. By putting that on a second line everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply ajax at your project.
call your server at every 5 minutes using ajax and refresh your content.
In short; AJAX is about loading data in the background and display it on the webpage, without reloading the whole page.